# s.d.e and a bound of $\mathbb E (\lvert X\rvert^2)$ which is not $t$-dependent

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t=X^x_t$ solution of the s.d.e :
$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t,\ X_0=x$$
Where $b$ and $\sigma$ are 1-lipschitzian.

I have proved that : *for all $t\geq 0$ it exists $L_t=L_t(x)>0$ s.t. $\mathbb E (\lvert X^x_t\rvert^2) \leq L_t e^{L_t t}$*
(I have done with classics maths tricks plus Gronwall theorem).

**But** the question of the exercise is : *Prove that there exists $L=L(x)>0$ s.t. $\mathbb E (\lvert X^x_t\rvert^2) \leq L e^{L t}, \forall t\geq 0$*. (literally transcripted)

Mean (I guess) that my prof requests to find $L$ which does not depend on $t$.

**My question is :** *Have I had a lack of understanding ? If yes, Do you have an idea for doing that ?* Because $t$ still appears if we use Cauchy-Schwartz/Jensen on the inequalities.

Comment: Maybe you can show that $L_t$ is bounded ?

Comment: I have shown : $\mathbb{E}\left[\mid X^x_t\mid^2\right] \leq 3x^2+3K(t+1)t+3K(t+1) \int^{t}_0 \mathbb{E}\left[\mid X^x_t\mid^2\right]ds$ $$\leq C_t(1+x^2)+C_t\int^{t}_0 \mathbb{E}\left[\mid X^x_t\mid^2\right]ds$$

And I have applied Gronwall : $f(t) \leq C_t(1+x^2)e^{C t}$ $$\leq C_t(1+x^2)e^{C_t(1+x^2) t} = L_te^{L_t t}$$

As for me I do not see how to bound $L_t$. Probably by fixing $T\geq t\geq 0$ ? or maybe a lack in the Lipschitz condition that I have not exploited fully ?

Comment: You can take $T>0$ then for all $t<T$, $L_t<L_T$. But if your calculus is right you cannot bound $L_t$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: So if the question was : *Prove that there exists $L=L(x)>0$ s.t. $\mathbb E (\mid X^x_t\mid^2) \leq L e^{L t}, \forall t\geq 0$*. This question is not correct ?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: I need an absolute certainty about this question.

Comment: Technical advice: `\mid` is (spaced as) a *binary relation*. You should *not* use it as a delimiter. That is what `\lvert` and `\rvert` are for, and even failing at that, simple `|` (or, synonymously, `\vert`) works better. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/40862

Comment: By Itô's formula, $Y_t=X_t^2$ solves $dY_t=2X_tdX_t+d\langle X\rangle_t=2X_tb(X_t)dt+2X_t\sigma(X_t)dB_t+\sigma^2(X_t)dt_t$ hence $dE(Y_t)=E(c(X_t))dt$ with $c(x)=2xb(x)+\sigma^2(x)$. If $b$ and $\sigma$ are both Lipschitz (with any Lipschitz constant) then $|c(x)|\leqslant k(1+x^2)$ for some finite $k$, for every $x$, hence $|c(X_t)|\leqslant k(1+Y_t)$ and the function $u$ defined by $u(t)=E(Y_t)$ solves $u'(t)\leqslant k(1+u(t))$, in particular $1+u(t)\leqslant(1+u(0))e^{kt}$ for every $t$, which ...

Comment: ... implies that $E((X_t^x)^2)\leqslant(1+x^2)e^{kt}$. (Unrelated: "*Is it a mistake of my prof (probable) ?*" Please avoid such unwarranted remarks.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments one simply applies Itô for $f(x)=x^2$

$$d(X_{t}^{2})=2X_{t}dX_{t}+\frac{1}{2}2d\langle X\rangle_{t}=\left(2X_{t}b(X_{t})+\sigma^{2}(X_{t})\right)dt+2X_{t}\sigma(X_{t})dB_{t}.$$

The Ito integral term has zero expectation as explained here [Dealing with a term coming from Ito formula.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354948/dealing-with-a-term-coming-from-ito-formula/4753117#4753117)

> A sufficient condition for the integral $\int_0^t f(\omega, s)\, dB_s$ to be a martingale on $[0,T]$ is that
>
> 1. $f(\omega,s)$ is adapted, measurable in s, *and*
> 2. $\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^T f^2(\omega,s)\,ds\right) < \infty$.
>    In this case, indeed, $\mathsf{E} \left(\int_0^T f(\omega,s)\, dB_s\right)=0$.

We are left with

$$E[X_{t}^{2}]=\int^tE\left[ \left(2X_{s}b(X_{s})+\sigma^{2}(X_{s})\right)\right]ds\leq ct+c \int^t E\left[ X_{s}^{2}\right]ds, $$

where $c$ depends on $x,\sigma(x),b(x)$ and so by the integral-version of Grownwall

$$E[X_{t}^{2}]\leq ct e^{ct}.$$